# I married an Asian citizen and I'm European. Does my husband need a visa to come to Europe?

Tags: visas, spain

I'm from Spain. My spouse is Mongolian. We want to travel to Europe. Also, we're waiting for his citizenship card (it takes 2 years).

Does he need a visa to go to Europe? After he gets the Spanish resident card, does he still need a visa to travel to Spain, or he can go without? I tried to call the embassy but I'm still confused and people give me different answers.

Comment: What is your husband’s nationality?

Comment: Mongolia , i found this article: europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm and say

Visa exemptions
Your non-EU spouse, (grand)children or (grand)parents do not need to get a visa from the country they are travelling to if:

They have a residence permit or visa from another country in the border-free Schengen area (see list below) and the country they are travelling to belongs to that area.

So maybe with residence permit he dont need visa.. or he still need visa?

Comment: Is the "citizenship card" you're waiting for a Mongolian document showing his Mongolian citizenship? Or has he been naturalized as a citizen of Spain?

Comment: No he have mongolian passport and he have soon the citizenship card

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you should do is register your marriage at the nearest Spanish embassy.

Your spouse does need a visa; however the visa should be expedited and granted to your spouse at a discounted cost.

Once your spouse is a permanent resident of Spain, they will not need a visa to travel to Spain.

Comment: we dont wont to get merried also in spain, his country is fine.
So he can travel we no visa when he have resident card? We live abroad but we are doing a lot of trip for work in europe